# Turn on/Turn off circuit using one momentary button. Also, turn off the circuit using a command from NodeMCU

Tags: power, switches, switching, nodemcu

I have this 5v and 3.3v voltage regulator circuit using 12v input voltage. This voltage regulator circuit is used to powerup my NodeMCU and several sensors.

Now, I'm having problems creating a circuit that:

1.) If plugged in, button hasn't been pressed yet, circuit is OFF.

2.) If plugged in, button is pressed, circuit will TURN ON.

3.) If plugged in, button is pressed again while circuit is Turned ON, circuit will be turned OFF.

4.) Turn OFF circuit when a command is received from NodeMCU.

So far, only 1-3 is the circuit I have. Your answers will be a great help especially circuit diagrams. Thank you.

[image: D6 goes to the voltage regulator]

Comment: That is a difficult schematic to understand.  It looks like you have created a flipflop with two relays.  Are you focused on relays, or are you open to an all solid state solution?  That is, a toggle flipflop (toggled with the switch) with a power-on set and with an explicit reset input for the uC; and a small power MOSFET as the power switch - ?

Comment: Why not just control the output with NodeMCU, use the switch as an input, and use a flip-flop logic? Do you need the control outside of the MCU?

Comment: pressing SW1 creates a short circuit between 12 V and GND  .... RL2 contacts common should be connected to D3 and D4